# django - This field is required

Tags: django, forms

I have two forms in my template and what I want to do is add the newly added model to an attribute of another model. The models are Customer and Order respectively. (Once I add a customer, i want to add an order with its customer, the newly added)

Here is my customer views

```
def add_customer(request):

    form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        customer = form.save(commit=False)
        customer.save()

        context = {
            'form': OrderForm()
        }

        messages.success(request, "Customer added successfully!")
        return render(request, 'orders/add_order.html', context)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'core/add_customer.html', context)
```

Here is my order views

```
def add_order(request):

    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None)
    orders = Order.objects.all()

    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.save()

        messages.success(request, "Order placed")
        return render(request, 'orders/index.html', {'orders': orders})

    return render(request, 'orders/add_order.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my template

```
<a href="{% url 'core:add-customer' %}">
    <p><em>Click this to add a new customer</em></p>
</a>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% include 'core/form-template.html' %}

    <div align="center">
        <button class="btn btn-success"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, the order can't be added since it throws the error (This field is required)

EDIT: Here are my forms

OrderForm

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['customer']
```

CustomerForm

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Order model

```
class Order(models.Model):

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)
```

Customer models

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    contact_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Comment: You should inlude source code of your models and forms.

Comment: you have to write a function which triggers the order process. Call the function in the `if form.is_valid():...` in the registration process.

Comment: Please include `models.py` and `forms.py` files.